# How to filter and sort array elements in ngtable?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have an array which I am using in ngtable, but need help in filtering data I am not able to do sort when I click on the header. Please help

HTML

```
<table class="table" ng-table="namingConventionParams" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in $data | orderBy:'toString()'">
        <td style="word-break:break-all" data-title="items.tableHeader" align="left" filter="{ '0': 'text' }" sortable="'valueOf()[0]'">{{item}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller

```
$scope.namingConventionParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1, // show first page
    count: 10
}, {
    defaultSort: "asc",
    total: $scope.items.instanceData.length, // length of data
    counts: [],
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        var data = $scope.items.instanceData;
        var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) : data;
            orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(orderedData, params.orderBy()) : orderedData;
            params.total(orderedData.length);
            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));            
    }
});
```

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/NnmvNXW4xbe2vw0VEO9L?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your array of data only contains strings instead of objects, so it's filtering based only on the first character when you have `sortable="valueOf()[0]"`

The solution is to use objects instead. Here is the relevant code that needs to be updated:

HTML

```
<td ... filter="{'name':'text'}" sortable="name">{{item.name}}</td>
```

JS

```
var data = $scope.items.instanceData.map(function(text) {
  return {name: text};
});
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9rVna6XTVyn2sW0mQkz2?p=preview)

Comment: Still filter does not work properly. `eg: ba` fails to give me any value, though data has `bay local mysql`

Comment: Clicking on the header to filter was what you wanted right? `http://g.recordit.co/vjbWcycZcd.gif`

Comment: Thank you for helping me in sorting, but I need help in both filter and sort. In filter or search only 1st character search is working. I am using filter and search as 1 term. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks. you changed the data to map which solves my problem, but someone might come looking for a solution with array elements.

Comment: @abi1964 "array elements" can mean objects or plain strings so the title of the question is not specific. I never used ngTable and my solution was based on just the ngTable docs in which I didn't find a solution for a simple array with just strings.

Comment: Can you help me with my problem in ngtable? I am providing [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383250/how-to-have-select-filter-in-ngtable)