# Two ngTables that use same data, but different filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, ngtable

What I'm trying to do is shown in this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JulieMarie/pen/zGXRjB).  In my real app, I have tabs, one for each table and this all works fine, but it seems like there's got to be a way to use just one table in the controller and call it with different filters from the view.

Something similar to this, but with a custom filter:

```
$scope.roleTable = new ngTableParams({
  page: 1,
  count: 10,
  sorting: {
    username: 'desc'
  }
}, {
  counts: [],
  getData: function ($defer, params) {
    var data = users;
    var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
        $filter('customFilter')(data, params.filter()) :
        data;
    params.total(orderedData.length);

    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), 
                                      params.page() * params.count()));
  }
});
```

Problem is, I can't figure out how to do it or if it's even possible?  I've search stackoverflow, tried passing in params directly from the view to the controller, as well as many other attempts and I can't get it to work.

Is what I want to do even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNoMxy?editors=101 ?

```
   $scope.filters = { role: "admin" };

   var options = {
      page: 1,
      count: 10,
      filter: $scope.filters,
      sorting: {
        username: 'desc'
      }
   };
```

Comment: however - it seems that this library can not do exact matches in filters? meaning "user" matches both "superuser" and "user".

Comment: ah it seemed they had a reported issue for that thing. here is one of the maintainers answer for that problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383250/how-to-have-select-filter-in-ngtable/31425502#31425502